# Web Interface identical to Qt user interface

Tags: qt, embedded, web-frontend

I'm working on a embedded system with a display. The user interface was developed using [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29).

How can I develop a web interface that looks identical to the existing Qt interface, and gives the same user experience on the web. The Qt GUI is accessing the device functionalities through an interface library.

- Is there a way to generate web pages using the existing Qt GUI code?
- Does any design approach exist that lets me re-use the existing Qt code?

Answer (score 2):

[QtWui](http://qtwui.sourceforge.net/) would be one option. Be warned, though, that it's a very young project.

Answer (score 1):

There was once an entry on the Qt Labs blog about a [QWebClient](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/09/18/qt-in-the-cloud-with-qwebclient/) which looked promising. The latest update to the git repository was in October 2009, however.

As alternatives, you could wait until both [Google’s Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) and the [Qt port that will run on it](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/12/17/take-it-with-a-grain-of-salt/) are stabilised/finished. The Native Client aims at running system code sandboxed in a browser, so you could ‘simply’ port your Qt app to run on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port in progress, compiling QT with Emscripten

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI3NDc

http://vps2.etotheipiplusone.com:30176/redmine/projects/emscripten-qt/wiki/Demos